# how to create Custom html helper for textboxes in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox, html-helper, custom-fields

I have three text boxes for Phone Number, which take Area Code, Prefix and Number.

My requirement is to create html helper class , so instead of taking three text boxes every where  in application where phone number is needed. i can use the custom html helper class for phone number.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static MvcHtmlString PhoneNumbers(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        string htmlTemplate = @"<input type="text" name='code'> <input type="text" name='Prefix'>  <input type="text" name='Number'>"
        return new MvcHtmlString(htmlTemplate);
    }
```

Use:

```
  @Html.PhoneNumbers();
```

Comment: thanks man!!!
 
it is working for me but by doing little changes in it...

public static MvcHtmlString PhoneNumbers(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            string htmlTemplate = "<input type=\"text\"  name='code'> <input type=\"text\" name='Prefix'>  <input type=\"text\" name='Number'>";
            return new MvcHtmlString(htmlTemplate);
        }

Can you tell me if how i can get all this text boxes value in single variable in helper class so it can be easy to store value in database.

Again Thanks..